# Align table columns with superscript markings

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table of integers; a handful of them have an extra superscript marks to distinguish various characteristics.

I think the table looks nice, but the superscript marks throw off the alignment. Can someone suggest how I can have the table elements right aligned and have the marks extend into the whitespace between the table columns?

An example of my table is given here

[image]

```
\begin{table}[p] \centering
    \caption{List of \SZA s for the \NDI\ data tables released with \MENDFx. The separations are merely for convenience and show the light ($Z < 25$), mid-weight ($25\leq Z < 89$) and the actinides. The \SZA s with an asterisk (*) indicate isotopes new to \ndf[1] and \SZA s new in the \MENDFx\ library.}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrrrrrrr}
        \toprule
        1001     & 1002    & 1003    & 2003    & 2004    & 3006    & 3007    & 4007$^{*\dagger}$   & 4009 \\
        5010     & 5011    & 6000    & 6012    & 7014    & 7015    & 8016    & 8017    & 9019 \\
        11022    & 11023   & 12024   & 12025   & 12026   & 13027   & 14028   & 14029   & 14030 \\
        15031    & 16032   & 16033   & 16034   & 16036   & 17035   & 17037   & 18036   & 18038 \\
        18040    & 19039   & 19040   & 19041   & 20040   & 20042   & 20043   & 20044   & 20046 \\
        20048    & 21045   & 22046   & 22047   & 22048   & 22049   & 22050   & 23050$^*$  & 23051$^*$ \\
        24050    & 24052   & 24053   & 24054   & 25055   & \\
        \midrule
        26054    & 26056$^\dagger$   & 26057   & 26058   & 27058   & 27059   & 28058   & 28059   & 28060 \\
        28061$^{\dagger}$    & 28062   & 28064   & 29063   & 29065   & 30064$^*$  & 30065$^*$  & 30066$^*$  & 30067$^*$ \\
        30068$^*$   & 30070$^*$  & 31069   & 31071   & 32070   & 32072   & 32073   & 32074   & 32076 \\
        33074    & 33075   & 34074   & 34076   & 34077   & 34078   & 34079   & 34080   & 34082 \\
        35079    & 35081   & 36078   & 36080   & 36082   & 36083   & 36084   & 36085   & 36086 \\
        37085    & 37086   & 37087   & 38084   & 38086   & 38087   & 38088   & 38089   & 38090 \\
        39089    & 39090   & 39091   & 40090   & 40091   & 40092   & 40093   & 40094   & 40095 \\
        40096    & 41093   & 41094   & 41095   & 42092   & 42094   & 42095   & 42096   & 42097 \\
        42098    & 42099   & 42100   & 43099   & 44096   & 44098   & 44099   & 44100   & 44101 \\
        44102    & 44103   & 44104   & 44105   & 44106   & 45103   & 45105   & 46102   & 46104 \\
        46105    & 46106   & 46107   & 46108   & 46110   & 47107   & 47109   & 47111   & 48106 \\
        48108    & 48110   & 48111   & 48112   & 48113   & 48114   & 48116   & 49113   & 49115 \\
        50112    & 50113   & 50114   & 50115   & 50116   & 50117   & 50118   & 50119   & 50120 \\
        50122    & 50123   & 50124   & 50125   & 50126   & 51121   & 51123   & 51124   & 51125 \\
        51126    & 52120   & 52122   & 52123   & 52124   & 52125   & 52126   & 52128   & 52130 \\
        52132    & 53127   & 53129   & 53130   & 53131   & 53135   & 54123   & 54124   & 54126 \\
        54128    & 54129   & 54130   & 54131   & 54132   & 54133   & 54134   & 54135   & 54136 \\
        55133    & 55134   & 55135   & 55136   & 55137   & 56130   & 56132   & 56133   & 56134 \\
        56135    & 56136   & 56137   & 56138   & 56140   & 57138   & 57139   & 57140   & 58136 \\
        58138    & 58139   & 58140   & 58141   & 58142   & 58143   & 58144   & 59141   & 59142 \\
        59143    & 60142   & 60143   & 60144   & 60145   & 60146   & 60147   & 60148   & 60150 \\
        61147    & 61148   & 61149   & 61151   & 62144   & 62147   & 62148   & 62149   & 62150 \\
        62151    & 62152   & 62153   & 62154   & 63151   & 63152   & 63153$^{\dagger}$   & 63154   & 63155 \\
        63156    & 63157   & 64152   & 64153   & 64154   & 64155   & 64156   & 64157   & 64158 \\
        64160    & 65159   & 65160   & 66156   & 66158   & 66160   & 66161   & 66162   & 66163 \\
        66164    & 67165   & 68162   & 68164   & 68166   & 68167   & 68168   & 68170   & 69168$^{*\dagger}$ \\
        69169$^*$   & 69170$^*$  & 71175   & 71176   & 72174   & 72176   & 72177   & 72178   & 72179 \\
        72180    & 73180$^*$  & 73181   & 73182   & 74180$^*$  & 74182   & 74183   & 74184   & 74186 \\
        75185    & 75187   & 77191   & 77193   & 79197   & 80196   & 80198   & 80199   & 80200 \\
        80201    & 80202   & 80204   & 81203$^*$  & 81205$^*$  & 82204   & 82206   & 82207   & 82208 \\
        83209    & 88223   & 88224   & 88225   & 88226   & \\
        \midrule
        89225    & 89226   & 89227   & 90227   & 90228   & 90229   & 90230   & 90231$^*$  & 90232 \\
        90233    & 90234   & 91229$^*$  & 91230$^*$  & 91231   & 91232   & 91233   & 92230   & 92231$^*$ \\
        92232    & 92233   & 92234   & 92235   & 92236   & 92237   & 92238   & 92239   & 92240 \\
        92241    & 93234   & 93235   & 93236   & 93237   & 93238   & 93239   & 94236   & 94237 \\
        94238    & 94239   & 94240   & 94241   & 94242   & 94243   & 94244   & 94246   & 95240$^*$ \\
        95241    & 95242   & 95243   & 95244   & 96240$^*$  & 96241   & 96242   & 96243   & 96244 \\
        96245    & 96246   & 96247   & 96248   & 96249   & 96250   & 97245$^*$  & 97246$^*$  & 97247$^*$ \\
        97248$^*$   & 97249   & 97250   & 98246   & 98248$^*$  & 98249   & 98250   & 98251   & 98252 \\
        98253$^*$   & 98254   & 99251$^*$  & 99252$^*$  & 99253$^*$  & 99254   & 99255   & 100255  & 1027058 \\
        1047110  & 1048115 & 1052127 & 1052129 & 1061148 & 1067166 & 1095242 & 1095244 & 1099254$^*$ \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \label{tab:SZAs}
\end{table}
```

Comment: use `\rlap{$^*$}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's exactly what I needed. What exactly does `\rlap` do?

Comment: @Jeremy: `\rlap` sets a `r`ight over-`lap` or a box of width `0pt` that is left-aligned (causing the overlap to the right).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- make that an answer (unless this question is a duplicate).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Doing what barbara says:

use

```
\rlap{$^*$}
```

(Note this hides the width of the marker so relies on inter-column space being large enough to avoid over-printing the next column)